# Why are strings beginning with a space converted with: ! ' with Ruby/YAML

Tags: ruby, yaml

I am writing a Ruby hash to a file using YAML.

```
File.open(output_file, "w") {|file| file.puts YAML::dump(final)}
```

The hash contains strings as keys and floats as values.

When my strings contain only letter they are outputted as such in the file file:

```
abc: 1.0
bcd: 1.0
cde: 1.0
```

When a string starts with a space it is outputted as such:

```
! ' ab': 1.0
```

When I read the file back in again everything is ok, but I want to know why this is happening and what does it mean.

I searched the YAML documentation and it says that a single exclamation point is used to represent local datatypes.

Why does this happen on string starting with spaces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`!` is known as the "non-specific tag"](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2785512). It forces the YAML engine to decode the following item as either a string, a hash, or an array. It basically disables interpreting it as a different type. I'm not sure why the engine is tagging them this way; it doesn't seem to be needed. Perhaps it is just overzealously attempting to remove ambiguity?

Edit: either way, it's unneeded syntax:

```
YAML.dump({' a'=>0})
=> "---\n! ' a': 0\n"
YAML.load("---\n! ' a': 0\n") # with the bang
=> {" a"=>0}
YAML.load("---\n' a': 0\n")   # without the bang
=> {" a"=>0}
```

Comment: I'm thinking it needs the string to be within quotes to confirm the space is part of the string. I've also checked the spec more and found in the section : "Example 7.8. Single Quoted Implicit Keys" the mention that : "All leading and trailing white space characters are excluded from the content.". I'm not certain, but I think it may need to use the ! to prevent the leading white space from being deleted ?

Comment: The leading and trailing whitespace it refers to are before and after the quotes. It can be shown that the `!` is unneeded by editing it out, and reloading the yaml, which loads exactly the same without the `!`